# Getting both Key Gestures and Executed method to work in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried `DelegateCommand` approach, it executes properly, but my key gestures do not work:

```
public DelegateCommand StageCommand { get; private set; }

...
StageCommand = new DelegateCommand(StageExecuted);
...

private void StageExecuted(object action)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("yay!");
}
```

And XAML for my Context Menu:

```
        <ContextMenu.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.StageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                        Gesture="Enter" />
        </ContextMenu.InputBindings>

        <MenuItem Header="Stage" Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.StageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}">
        </MenuItem>
```

All this executes properly, but I am missing the key gesture, it does not even display it:

[image]

This is how I use the context menu:

```
<DataGrid 
          ContextMenu="{DynamicResource TestContextMenu}"
          Tag="{Binding}">
```

**Update:**

If I press `Enter` *while* the context menu is open, it executes. How can I make it so that it executes as long as the control that has the context menu attached to it has focus? And also, it still does not display the gesture key.

Comment: Did you look at the docs? You just specify the **name of the method**. You are limited to methods on your window or whatever object the XAML belongs to.

Comment: Does this command *need* to be a RoutedCommand or could you use the MVVM approach and adopt RelayCommand/DelegateCommand?

Comment: @sixlettervariables Yes `DelegateCommand` is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.inputgesturetext.aspx) for `MenuItem.InputGestureText`:

> This property does not associate the input gesture with the menu item; it simply adds text to the menu item. The application must handle the user's input to carry out the action.

Basically, because that is purely a text field for displaying an input gesture to users in the default `MenuItem` Control Template there is no association between it and some command you've decided to wire-up with a `KeyBinding`.

You could handle this through a binding, or a `StaticResource`, or maybe thru an attached property/behavior which searches the `KeyBinding`s and assigns input gestures to any child which uses the matching command.

Comment: Hi, see my update #2. I'm now using `DelegateCommand`, which executes fine, but I lost key gestures. They don't work nor show up.

Comment: Yes I realized that now. I've updated my question to be clearer. I tried `Gesture` and `Key` and neither seem to work :/

Comment: Ah, I now see your problem. The `InputGestureText` on a `MenuItem` knows nothing about your `KeyBinding` of some random command. It is merely a display field used by the default `ControlTemplate` of the `MenuItem`. You'll have to bind or set the `InputGestureText` on the item as well.

Comment: I see. I just updated my question. Do you think I can still make the execution behavior better (see the updated question)?

Comment: @rFactor: those are two different problems. The second problem I've answered (i.e. the display issue). The first problem is because your key binding is for the context menu, not the `DataGrid`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a [`CommandBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding.aspx) for the command in some control's [`InputBindings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputbindings.aspx).

Comment: See my update, I don't know how can I get around with that approach.

Comment: @H.B. perhaps the OP is looking for RelayCommand/DelegateCommand?

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Probably a better approach if the method is defined in the DataContext or something similar.